# How to get elements of a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a set of nodes

```
nodes = ["uno","dos","tres","cuatro","cinco","seis"]
```

and a set of edges

```
edges = [("uno", "dos"),
     ("uno", "tres"), 
     ("dos", "tres"), 
     ("dos", "cuatro"), 
     ("tres", "cuatro"), 
     ("tres", "cinco"), 
     ("cuatro", "cinco"), 
     ("cuatro", "seis"), 
     ("cinco", "seis")]
```

I have defined the inverse of these edges

```
inverses =[(j,i) for (i,j) in edges]
```

And now I have my set of arcs

```
arcs = edges + inverses
```

My problem is that I want to get all the elements in the set of arcs which have a determined first element. That is

```
ArcsOut[i in nodes] = [(i,j) for (i,j) in arcs for i in nodes for j in nodes].
```

I want to obtain something like this. If I order to get all arcs that have their fist component "uno", I would like to have:

```
ArcsOut["uno"]= [("uno", "dos"),("uno", "tres"),("dos", "uno"),("tres", "uno")]
```

But I do not know how I can order that.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: What is the variable `stations`?

Comment: @Aaron, sorry, there was an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following syntax to create a dictionary:

```
ArcsOut = dict(((i,[(k,l) for k,l in arcs if k == i]) for (i,j) in arcs))
```

Then ArcsOut['unos'] = desired output.

/* EDIT */

Performancewise consider using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
ArcsOut = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in arcs:
    ArcsOut[k].append((k,v))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a list comprehension. The nice part is you can use the tuple unpacking together with the condition to make it very short and to the point, at the same time readable.

```
arc_out = {node: [(i, j) for i, j in arcs if i == node] for node in nodes]
```

Instead, if you want to get all edges where *either* `i` or `j` matches a specific node name, you can do this

```
[edge for edge in arcs if 'uno' in edge]
```

Comment: But I would like to get a general valid expression depending on the node "i"

Comment: The above is both valid and can be easily be generalized for any "i".

Comment: how it could be generalized? If I write this  ArcsOut[i in nodes] = [(i,j) for (i,j) in arcs for i in nodes for j in nodes] I get an error code

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I added a dict comphrehension as well. It will do the same, but for all nodes and put it in a dict

Comment: Thanks! this is all I was looking for!